# R Caret Calculate RMSE for Testing Set

Tags: r, r-caret

I am wondering how can I calculate RMSE for the Testing Set.

I used the code below to train the model:

```
model_gbm_important<-train(trainSetSmall[,predictors_gbm],trainSetSmall[,outcomeName],method='gbm', trControl=fitControl)
```

I can get the performance of the model by using

```
print(model_gbm_important)
```

However, this performance is based on the cross-validation. If I have another testing set, how can I use testing set to evaluate the model, lick check the value of RMSE?

Thanks!

Comment: This is more of a methods question than a coding question. You will probably find wide differences of opinion about the best way to express uncertainty around model estimates for GBM models. Perhaps posting the question on the SE Machine Learning site would be more on topic. Voting to close as opinion-based, but if SO had the option of migrating to the Machine Learning/Data Science forum I would have chosen that reason to close/migrate.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstood the question: it seems like the OP is looking for the function RMSE.

Comment: If so he should have offered a data and code example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate RMSE of prediction of test data:

```
predictions <- predict(model, test_data)
RMSE(predictions, test_data$outcomeName)
```